# The Interpretation of Objective in Variational Autoencoder

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

The objective is, $\log P(X) - \mathcal{D}[Q(z|X)||P(z|X)]=E_{z\sim Q}[\log P(X|z)] - \mathcal{D}[Q(z|X)||P(z)]$.

Obviously, $\log P(X) \geq E_{z\sim Q}[\log P(X|z)]$ (by Jensen's inequality).

So we can directly have $\mathcal{D}[Q(z|X)||P(z|X)] \geq \mathcal{D}[Q(z|X)||P(z)]$, which means $P(z|X)$ is further from $Q(z|X)$ than $P(z)$ does according to the interpretation of $\mathcal{D}$ KL-divergence, seemingly against the intuition.

So why? How to explain it?

Thank you.

[Enclosed (C. Doersch et. al. 2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf) is the reference to VAE.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I am aware of that. But $P(x)$ is identical to $E_{z\sim P(\cdot|X)}[\log P(X|z)]=\int_z P(X|z)P(z|X)dz$ right? So there is no an intuitive way to compare these two. So could you directly proof that $P(x) < E_{z\sim Q}[\log P(X|z)]$? Thank you again.

Comment: No, $P(X)$ is identical to $E_{z \sim P(z)} = \int_z P(X|z) P(z) dz$. Not sure what you mean by "an intuitive way to compare these two", why do you need to compare the two sides? A good way to think of the objective (the left hand side) is that it tries to both increase the likelihood of data (the $\log P(X)$ term) and to force the actual decoder $Q(z|X)$ to be close to the optimal decoder $P(z|X)$.

Comment: I have just been pointed out that the notation the material uses is ambiguous and $\int_z P(X|z)P(z|X)dz \to P(X)$. Thank you for answering. Could you please post your answer at the Answer area for I will accept it?

Comment: Are you sure, e.g. given Eq. 1 in the attached? Anyhow, I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $P(X) = \int p(X\vert z) P(z) dz$, per Eq. 1. Thus,  while
$$ E_{z \sim Q}[\log P(X\vert z)]= \int  Q(z) [\log P(X\vert z)] dz \le \log \left[\int Q(z) P(X\vert z) dz\right]$$
by Jensen's inequality, this is not the same as $\log P(X)$.

A good way to think of the objective in Eq. 4, $\log P(X) - D[Q(z)\Vert P(z|X)]$, is that maximizing it both increases the likelihood of data (the $\log P(X)$ term) and forces the actual decoder $Q(z)$ to be close to the optimal decoder $P(z|X)$ (the KL-divergence term).